# WatchService issues - logfile doesn't refresh on modification

Tags: java, windows-10, watchservice

I use a (third-party) Windows10 application, which generates .txt log files. In my own application I wrote a class, which uses WatchService and observes the folder for these .txt changes. I know my class works correctly, becuase I tested with other files/JUnit. During testing changes are picked up right away, all correct.

In case of the .txt logs nothing gets picked up.

I played around and noticed, that my application pickes up the updates only if I go to the explorer window and hit F5 (refresh). Size of the file is refreshed and also my WatchService fires an update.

Any idea why this weird behaviour would happen? It probably is on the log application level or Windows itself, but I wonder if anyone can come up with a solution to this with Java?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no suggestion I will share what I did, solution I don't particularly like, but perhaps it will be helpfull to someone.

In order to refresh the folder I simply created a loop, which checks for file sizes. The below code checks sizes of all files, but if you know the exact name of the file, you could also implement this for that particular file.

```
File folder = new File("C:\\path\\to\\logs\\");
while (true)
{
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (File f : listOfFiles)
    {
        System.out.println("\tFile size: " + f.length());
    }
}
```

You can also change the sleep value from 5000 (5seconds) if you need it checked more or less often.